# Are default mysql parameters in RDS sane?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

RDS uses the same set of parameters for all instance sizes and they don't seem to be that far from defaults (max_packet_size being too small etc.)

Has anyone looked at them and reviewed them for how sensible they are, especially on relatively bigger instances?

Comment: Bear in mind that in most cases these are tuned to your application...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default buffer size for MyISAM is too small in RDS parameter group, I have made changes of that, make significant improvement in read/write performance. However, just beware, not all MySQL parameters are honored by RDS, only those ones shown in parameter group.

Answer (score -3):

you can always change the parameter set to fit your application.